# Deleting elements from numpy or list in python

Tags: python, list

So I'm generating images of curvy lines.  I build my lines out of the first few modes of a fourier series (using randomly chosen amplitudes on each cosine function) and then generate a list of x and y values from my fourier series for the curvy line.  But now I'd like to plot y vs x, on my own terms, since I need lots of control and pyplot does too much under the hood.

So I cast my x and y vectors (1D numpy arrays) into integers, so that now they refer to pixel positions (everything is scaled to fit in a 128x128 img window).  Now I would like to eliminate redundancies from my vectors (ie. wherever I have a repeated x AND y value, I want to remove that x from the x vector and that y from the y vector).

Currently, x and y are in two different vectors.  Would it be better to keep them as a single vector of ordered pairs?  Then it would be a matter of removing redundant ordered pairs.

Either way, what's the ideal route to knocking out the redundancies.  I feel like I'm coding around the bush (teehee) on this one and there's got to be a simple pythonic route.

Thanks people.

Comment: Removing redundant ordered pairs is extremely trivial, list(set(l)), I would definitely do that.  Zipping the pairs is trivial, too-- zip(a, b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it'd be better to keep the points in pairs (tuples). If you don't want to rewrite all the code and just make some test, [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) the two arrays to obtain the list of points:

```
points = zip(x_list, y_list)
```

Now that you have the list of points, generate a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) from your list of points (and it will automatically throw the duplicate pairs) and then obtain a list again:

```
points = list(set(points))
```